# I have legacy product using JavaCC v4, what is the changes from then to v6?

Tags: java, javacc

I have to maintain legacy product using JavaCC v4, what are the changes from then to v6?

I plan to use the v6 documentation, latest Eclipse plugin etc. I wanted to know what are the changes from JavaCC v4 to v6. I do **not** plan to upgrade the code, as I said it is legacy code that is being maintained.

I tried looking into the JavaCC v6 Release Notes, they almost make me feel that the *only* changes were addition of C++ support. Is that true?

I am a new to JavaCC, I have worked to some extent on on ANTLR, Flex/Bison.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are referring to the [release notes](https://javacc.java.net/doc/javaccreleasenotes.html) page.  I think there is more to it than that.  I found release bundles for 4.1, 4.1d, 4.2 and 5.0 in the javacc [downloads area](https://java.net/projects/javacc/downloads).  If you are looking for a detailed listing of what changed, you probably need to download each of the releases and check their contents for Release Notes / READMEs / whatever.

(Alternatively, trawl through the issues that are marked as "fixed" in the respective release milestones.  There are example issue-tracker links in the release notes page; see above.)

But you can probably get away with treating 6.0 as a drop-in replacement for 4.0.  IMO, it is worth just giving it a try.  If anything has changed in ways that are not backwards compatible, your "plan" may be thwarted.  So you may as well be optimistic about it ...

Comment: Thx Stephen, I did download the release bundles for 5.0 and 6.0 and found the similarly sparse release notes (nearly identical to the link you pointed to). The fix tracker link in the rel notes are also outdated. Although I think it is possible to directly reach it from the main website.